# Intellij Idea Community Edition 2018.3.6 is behaving very slow

Tags: intellij-idea

I ma using Intellij Idea Community Edition 2018.3.6 . Its behaving very slow suddenly. I tried updating the idea64.exe.vmoptions with the below values.
-Xms128m
-Xmx8192m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m

It didn't help. 
I am using JRE1.8.0_152
Please suggest.

Comment: Is it necessary to stay at 2018.3.6? Maybe you could update to 2019.something?

Answer (score 0):

Please [contact the support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new) team with the [CPU snapshot](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241235) attached.

One of the [known issues](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005028939-Slow-startup-on-Windows-splash-screen-appears-in-more-than-20-seconds) is the antivirus, but it mostly affects the startup. If it's slow during the regular work, it could be something else and only the CPU snapshot can help to identify the root case.

I can also suggest upgrading to the [current version](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html) and see if it works better for you.